# FBSDKAccessToken access denied Tinder API

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to get the authentication token of Tinder API by sending FB token like described in following documentation:
https://gist.github.com/rtt/10403467

I'm using objective c and I'm getting the fb access token from FBSDK. The response says me only that access is denied so I think there is something wrong with the fb access token. The facebook test user account I'm using is also already registered on Tinder.
What is wrong with this?

FB token:

```
FBSDKAccessToken *token = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken];
```

This is my request:

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.gotinder.com/auth"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"Tinder/6.1.0 (iPhone; iOS 9.3; Scale/2.00)" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
    [request setValue:@"ios" forHTTPHeaderField:@"platform"];
[request setValue:@"3" forHTTPHeaderField:@"app-version"];
[request setHTTPBody:postdata];
```